# Vectorizing a variable length look-ahead loop in pandas

Tags: pandas

This is a very simplified version of my data:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
|    | user_id | seconds_since_start |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  0 |       1 |                  10 |
|  1 |       1 |                  12 |
|  2 |       1 |                  15 |
|  3 |       1 |                  52 |
|  4 |       1 |                  60 |
|  5 |       1 |                  67 |
|  6 |       1 |                 120 |
|  7 |       2 |                  55 |
|  8 |       2 |                  62 |
|  9 |       2 |                 105 |
| 10 |       3 |                 200 |
| 11 |       3 |                 206 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

And this is the data I would like to produce:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|    | user_id | seconds_since_start | session_ordinal | session_duration |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|  0 |       1 |                  10 |               1 |                5 |
|  1 |       1 |                  12 |               1 |                5 |
|  2 |       1 |                  15 |               1 |                5 |
|  3 |       1 |                  52 |               2 |               15 |
|  4 |       1 |                  60 |               2 |               15 |
|  5 |       1 |                  67 |               2 |               15 |
|  6 |       1 |                 120 |               3 |                0 |
|  7 |       2 |                  55 |               1 |                7 |
|  8 |       2 |                  62 |               1 |                7 |
|  9 |       2 |                 105 |               2 |                0 |
| 10 |       3 |                 200 |               1 |                6 |
| 11 |       3 |                 206 |               1 |                6 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

My notion of a session is a group of events from a single user which occur not more than 10 seconds apart, and a session's duration is defined as the difference between the first event in the session and the last event (in seconds).

I have written working Python that achieves what I want.

```python
import pandas as pd

events_data = [[1, 10], [1, 12], [1, 15], [1, 52], [1, 60], [1, 67], [1, 120], 
    [2, 55], [2, 62], [2, 105], 
    [3, 200], [3, 206]]
events = pd.DataFrame(data=events_data, columns=['user_id', 'seconds_since_start'])

def record_session(index_range, ordinal, duration):
    for i in index_range:
        events.at[i, 'session_ordinal'] = ordinal
        events.at[i, 'session_duration'] = duration

session_indexes = []
current_user = previous_time = session_start = -1
session_num = 0
for i, row in events.iterrows():
    if row['user_id'] != current_user or (row['seconds_since_start'] - previous_time) > 10:
        record_session(session_indexes, session_num, previous_time - session_start)
        session_indexes = [i]
        session_num += 1
        session_start = row['seconds_since_start'] 
    if row['user_id'] != current_user:
        current_user = row['user_id']
        session_num = 1
    previous_time = row['seconds_since_start']
    session_indexes.append(i)
record_session(session_indexes, session_num, previous_time - session_start)
```

My problem is the length of time this takes to run. As I said, this is a very simplified version of my data, my actual data has 70,000,000 rows. Is there a way to vectorize (and thus speed-up) algorithms like this that formulate additional columns based on variable length look-aheads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
# Create a helper boolean Series
s = df.groupby('user_id')['seconds_since_start'].diff().gt(10)

df['session_ordinal'] = s.groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().add(1).astype(int)

df['session_duration'] = (df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_ordinal'])['seconds_since_start']
                          .transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()))
```

[output]

```
    user_id  seconds_since_start  session_ordinal  session_duration
0         1                   10                1                 5
1         1                   12                1                 5
2         1                   15                1                 5
3         1                   52                2                15
4         1                   60                2                15
5         1                   67                2                15
6         1                  120                3                 0
7         2                   55                1                 7
8         2                   62                1                 7
9         2                  105                2                 0
10        3                  200                1                 6
11        3                  206                1                 6
```

Comment: so long as your `by=` arg in groupby is the same length as the `Series` or `DataFrame` you are grouping, you could use any list, array, series etc to group... You're not restricted to columns within "self" if you like.  Another way to think of it, suppose `s` above was instead a `DataFrame`... then you assigned a new column `s['user_id'] = df['user_id]`... then `s.groupby('user_id') ....` . The method above is essentially doing this, but referencing directly from `df`

Comment: (Sorry, deleted my question! I mentioned that I didn't understand grouping one DataFrame by a column in another. Thanks for the explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

[Chris A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10201580/chris-a)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55646727/575530) is great. It contains several techniques or calls I was unfamiliar with. This answer copies his and adds copious annotations.

We start by building a helper Boolean series. This series records which events start *additional* sessions for any user. This is OK as a Boolean series because *in numeric contexts they behave like the integers 0 and 1* (quoting from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)). Let's put the series together bit by bit.

```python
starts_session = events.groupby('user_id')['seconds_since_start'].diff().gt(10)
```

First we group events by user_id ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)) and then choose the 'seconds_since_start' column and call diff ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)) on that. The result of `events.groupby('user_id')['seconds_since_start'].diff()`is

```
+----+----------------------+
|    |  seconds_since_start |
+----+----------------------+
|  0 |                  NaN |
|  1 |                  2.0 |
|  2 |                  3.0 |
|  3 |                 37.0 |
|  4 |                  8.0 |
|  5 |                  7.0 |
|  6 |                 53.0 |
|  7 |                  NaN |
|  8 |                  7.0 |
|  9 |                 43.0 |
| 10 |                  NaN |
| 11 |                  6.0 |
+----+----------------------+
```

I can see that the start of each group is already picking up the correct NaN difference as there's no previous event from that user to give a delta from.

Then using the element-wise greater than `gt(10)` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html)) we get

```
+----+----------------------+
|    |  seconds_since_start |
+----+----------------------+
|  0 |                False |
|  1 |                False |
|  2 |                False |
|  3 |                 True |
|  4 |                False |
|  5 |                False |
|  6 |                 True |
|  7 |                False |
|  8 |                False |
|  9 |                 True |
| 10 |                False |
| 11 |                False |
+----+----------------------+
```

(N.B. The column heading is odd, but it is not used and so does not matter.)

```
events['session_ordinal'] = starts_session.groupby(events['user_id']).cumsum().add(1).astype(int)
```

We then re-group starts_session by the user_ids in events and then do the cumulative sum `cumsum` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)) over each group. The grouping does the work for us here ensuring that each user's events are restarted at zero. We need the session ordinal to start at 1 not zero so we simply add one `add(1)` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)) and we cast them to int as none of them are NaN `astype(int)` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)). This gives the derived session_ordinal column I wanted.

```
events['session_duration'] = events.groupby(['user_id', 'session_ordinal'])['seconds_since_start'].transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

To derive each session's duration we first group events by both the user_id and the new session_ordinal, i.e. we group them into sessions. Using `transform` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)) we find the minimum and maximum value of seconds_since_start for each group (i.e. each session) and the difference between them is the session's duration. This pattern, applying `transform` to grouped data is used extensively in the [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) process.

Thanks Chris.